# template argument deduction/substitution in operator

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, operator-overloading

I have a set of classes derived from one base:

```
template<typename Traits>
class Base{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual scalar_t apply(const scalar_t&) const=0;
};

template<typename Traits>
class Pover_of_Number:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  Pover_of_Number(const scalar_t& power):
  power(power){}
  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return pow(value,power);
  }
private:
  scalar_t power;
};

template<typename Traits>
class Mult_by_Number:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  Mult_by_Number(const scalar_t& num):
  num(num){}

  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return num*value;
  }
private:
  scalar_t num;
};

template<typename Traits>
class SumOperator:
public Base<Traits>{
  typedef Base<Traits> BT;
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  SumOperator(const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op1,
              const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op2):
  op1{op1}, op2{op2}{}

  scalar_t apply(const scalar_t& value) const override{
    return op1->apply(value)+op2->apply(value);
  }
private:
  std::shared_ptr<BT> op1;
  std::shared_ptr<BT> op2;
};
```

With some particular `Traits` this code works perfectly:

```
class TraitsExample{
public:
  typedef double scalar_t;
};

int main(){
  auto op1=std::make_shared<Pover_of_Number<TraitsExample>>(2.);
  auto op2=std::make_shared<Mult_by_Number<TraitsExample>>(10.);

  //works correctly
  auto sumop=std::make_shared<SumOperator<TraitsExample>>(op1,op2);
  std::cout<<sumop->apply(2.)<<std::endl;
```

Now I want to overload `operator+` which used my derived classes (3=1+2):

```
template<typename Traits>
std::shared_ptr<SumOperator<Traits>> operator+(
  const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op1,
  const std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>& op2){
  return std::make_shared<SumOperator<Traits>>(op1,op2);
}
```

However when I use it in the code I have a `template argument deduction/substitution failed` error.

Could someone explain to me what exactly needs to be done in order for gcc to compile my code, preferably without using any additional classes for deduction.

PS: One can find working [example](http://cpp.sh/66rm). As I said I need additionally to overload `+` operator.

Comment: provide a complete self contained testcase

Comment: A `shared_ptr<Derived>` is not a `shared_ptr<Base>`, though you can implicitly convert from one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trouble here is that the compiler can't deduce `Traits` from trying to match argument type `std::shared_ptr<Pover_of_Number<TraitsExample>>` against parameter type `std::shared_ptr<Base<Traits>>`.  There's an implicit conversion involved in converting from the first to `std::shared_ptr<Base<TraitsExample>>`, so the deduction can't happen automatically.

I would add a public `typedef` to your `Base<Traits>` class and use that to figure out what the return type of `operator+` should be:

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename Traits>
class Base{
  typedef typename Traits::scalar_t scalar_t;
public:
  using traits_type = Traits;
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual scalar_t apply(const scalar_t&) const=0;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_same<typename T::traits_type, typename U::traits_type>::value,
                 std::shared_ptr<SumOperator<typename T::traits_type>>> operator+(
  const std::shared_ptr<T>& op1,
  const std::shared_ptr<U>& op2){
  return std::make_shared<SumOperator<typename T::traits_type>>(op1,op2);
}
```

Note that due to SFINAE, this `operator+` won't incorrectly match anything without a `traits_type` member.

[Full demo.](http://cpp.sh/6k6f4)